# Problems related to perl smartmatch operator

Tags: perl

For the given input file words.txt, filter all lines containing characters in ascending

`f`:

```
bot
art
are
boat
toe
flee
reed
```

1)

```
# perl -F -lane 'print if $_ eq join "", sort @F' f
bot
art
```

2)

```
# perl -F -lane '@b = sort @F;if(@F~~@b){print $_}' f 
bot
art
```

The first two methods are correct, but why is the third one without results?

3)

```
# perl -F -lane 'print if sort @F~~@F' f
```

In addition, Does the smartmatch operator (`~~`) have shortcomings

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you shouldn't be using the smartmatch operator.

It's an experimental feature. (Using it results in a warning with 5.18+ even if you don't enable warnings, although the warning can be muted.) It could be changed or removed at any time.

Furthermore, it's considered a failed experiment. Its design is considered buggy.

---

You have two problems.

The first is a precedence problem. `sort @F ~~ @F` means `sort( @F ~~ @F )`. Parens would solve this problem.

```perl
( sort @F ) ~~ @F
```

But this doesn't work either. You don't have an array or array reference on the left-hand side, so you don't get the `ARRAY ~~ ARRAY` behaviour you want. To get that behaviour, you could use

```perl
[ sort @F ] ~~ @F
```